# AttributeError:module 'torchtext.data' has no attribute 'TabularDataset'

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, torchtext

I want to create a dataset from a tsv file with pytorch.
I was thinking of using

```
torchtext.data.TabularDataset.splits
```

but I'm getting an error message.

```
AttributeError:module 'torchtext.data' has no attribute 'TabularDataset'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `torchtext.legacy.data.TabularDataset.splits`